# Open the Outlook meeting window with a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook

I got a Windows form with a button (C#). This button should open the Outlook Meeting window which looks like this:

[image: Outlook Meeting window]

The button has to open the window so the user can create a Meeting. Can you help me ?

Comment: Is this your Homework? Sho us what you already tried and where you have issues

Comment: First I tried to create a Windows form where the user can fill in the Subject, , day , time and so on ..  but i didn´t find a good way to : 1. Add the GAL of Outlook and 2. I didn´t finde a way to Show that the Meeting room is blocked or not on the day of the Meeting.... I know therse a way to automatically create a Meeting Request.. So I thought it is easier to open the original Outlook window . The issue is that i didn´t find a way ( C# methode) which just open the Outlook window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your WinForms Application with a button and execute this code on button click:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); ;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem appointmentItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApplication.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem); 

appointmentItem.Subject = "Meeting Subject";
appointmentItem.Body = "The body of the meeting";
appointmentItem.Location = "Room #1";
appointmentItem.Start = DateTime.Now;
appointmentItem.Recipients.Add("test@test.com");
appointmentItem.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
appointmentItem.ReminderSet = true;
appointmentItem.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15;
appointmentItem.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
appointmentItem.BusyStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;
appointmentItem.Recipients.ResolveAll();
appointmentItem.Display(true);
```

It will open an appointment window from Outlook.

To get this working you need a reference to *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook*

Comment: the question asked for meeting window, this code will open appointment window, see my answer...

Comment: @Shamshiel Thank you for you help .... But i need to ask something ... this code run locally fine on my machine ... but the same code when i uploaded to server as app service on azure cloud i am getting error ... it saying that no instance for outlook file ... Little abt my application ... I assign training to employees, when i click on assign button i want to open meeting pop with whatever header and body i provide through application.
Is it possible to do so...opening user outlook meeting invitation from application hosted on cloud.
Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2):

The @Shamshiel answer will open an `appointment window`!

For `meeting window`, you must set the appointmentItem attribute of `MeetingStatus`.

```
appointmentItem.MeetingStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
```

Note that you can not create the `MeetingItem Object`: ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/meetingitem-object-outlook))

> Unlike other Microsoft Outlook objects, you cannot create this object.
>   It is created automatically when you set the MeetingStatus property of
>   an AppointmentItem object to olMeeting and send it to one or more
>   users. They receive it in their inboxes as a MeetingItem.
>
> Use the GetAssociatedAppointment method to return the AppointmentItem
>   object associated with a MeetingItem object, and work directly with
>   the AppointmentItem object to respond to the request.