# Is it possible to directly open the Outlook meeting window?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-2016

I am trying to have my application to open the Outlook meeting window with some pre-populated fields.

I have found that this question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098485/open-the-outlook-meeting-window-with-a-button).
However, the code provided in the answer(which works fine) doesn't open the meeting window but the appointement window. Those are two different things that are handled differently in Outlook and what I need is indeed the meeting window.

Is there any way to achieve this or do I absolutely have to open the appointement window first and then invite people to turn it into a meeting?

Comment: Using the linked code try adding `appointmentItem.MeetingStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;` before `.Display()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open the Outlook meeting window with a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098485/open-the-outlook-meeting-window-with-a-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an appointment just as in the other question, but then set the `MeetingStatus` property of the appointment.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); ;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem appointmentItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApplication.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);

// This line was added    
appointmentItem.MeetingStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;

appointmentItem.Subject = "Meeting Subject";
appointmentItem.Body = "The body of the meeting";
appointmentItem.Location = "Room #1";
appointmentItem.Start = DateTime.Now;
appointmentItem.Recipients.Add("test@test.com");
appointmentItem.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
appointmentItem.ReminderSet = true;
appointmentItem.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15;
appointmentItem.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
appointmentItem.BusyStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;
appointmentItem.Recipients.ResolveAll();
appointmentItem.Display(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know if there is a similar way to display the skype meeting window?

Comment: @Patsuan Sorry, no idea. Don't use skype.

Answer (score 0):

One more note to NineBerries good solution, because I had an issue here:

The line

```
appointmentItem.Recipients.ResolveAll();
```

is necessary if you have optional attendees in the meeting.
Otherwise they will be reset to "required" even if you set

```
recipient.Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olOptional;
```

before, which is due to "late auto-resolving" of names in Outlook (or so it seems).