# Is it possible to directly open the outlook meeting window with javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to have the outlook meeting window pop up with pre-populated fields, upon the click of a button. The answers I have seen work for c# but I cant seem to make it work for js. For reference the answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676261/is-it-possible-to-directly-open-the-outlook-meeting-window)

Comment: Have you tried the API displayNewAppointmentFormAsync? This API allows an add-in to create a new appointment/meeting window with the attendees, location, subject, start, and end pre-populated. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-mailbox-displaynewappointmentformasync-member(2)

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I put the code from the js example in the docs to execute upon a button click, however I am getting this error whenever it is clicked "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'displayNewAppointmentFormAsync') ". I have included the url for the api in a script tag as well.

Comment: Can you share code snippets to help us understand where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. `OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that. Outlook web add-ins work under the context of currently selected item in Outlook. The best what you could do is to use EWS or Graph API for dealing with other items, but not displaying them in Outlook programmatically.